# Connect Timeout Apache Ignite 2.1 .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I connect to a cluster with a .net client and next simulate that the ethernet cable is disconnected. The .Net client hangs about 30 - 60 seconds and next the IgniteClientDisconnectedException is thrown.

I want that it hangs for less time. I already tryied to change joinTimeout, networkTimeout, clientFailureDetectionTimeout, failureDetectionTimeout, socketTimeout but it seems that nothing solve that.

Can anyone explain me why?

This is the log when it starts to give the exception:

> 2017-09-04 17:14:11,070 [ERROR] [63] TcpDiscoverySpi - Exception on
>   joining: connect timed out 2017-09-04 17:14:11,071 [DEBUG] [63]
>   TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to join to address
>   [addr=/161.27.45.134:47504, recon=true,
>   errs=[java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out,
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]] 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,071 [ERROR] [63] TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to reconnect to
>   cluster (consider increasing 'networkTimeout' configuration property)
>   [networkTimeout=5000] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,071 [DEBUG] [63]
>   TcpDiscoverySpi - Grid runnable finished normally:
>   tcp-client-disco-reconnector-#5%null% 2017-09-04 17:14:11,072 [DEBUG]
>   [23] TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to restore closed connection, will try
>   to reconnect [networkTimeout=5000, joinTimeout=5000, failMsg=null]
>   2017-09-04 17:14:11,077 [DEBUG] [23] TcpDiscoverySpi - Discovery
>   notification [node=TcpDiscoveryNode
>   [id=341136db-9447-4abe-ad06-c10915c3e671, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
>   127.0.0.1, 161.27.44.226], sockAddrs=[/161.27.44.226:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=0,
>   lastExchangeTime=1504537928695, loc=true,
>   ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true],
>   type=CLIENT_NODE_DISCONNECTED, topVer=16] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,083
>   [DEBUG] [23] GridContinuousProcessor - onDisconnected [rmtInfos={},
>   locInfos={773f91e4-46ee-4066-8271-3db15a8a823d=LocalRoutineInfo
>   [prjPred=null, hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandler
>   [cacheName=ignite-sys-cache, rmtFilter=null, rmtFilterDep=null,
>   internal=true, notifyExisting=false, oldValRequired=true, sync=false,
>   ignoreExpired=true, taskHash=0, skipPrimaryCheck=false,
>   locCache=false, keepBinary=false, ackBuf=null, cacheId=-2100569601,
>   initTopVer=null, nodeLeft=false, ignoreClsNotFound=false,
>   asyncCb=false, nodeId=null, routineId=null], bufSize=1, interval=0,
>   autoUnsubscribe=true]},
>   clientInfos={341136db-9447-4abe-ad06-c10915c3e671={773f91e4-46ee-4066-8271-3db15a8a823d=LocalRoutineInfo
>   [prjPred=null, hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandler
>   [cacheName=ignite-sys-cache, rmtFilter=null, rmtFilterDep=null,
>   internal=true, notifyExisting=false, oldValRequired=true, sync=false,
>   ignoreExpired=true, taskHash=0, skipPrimaryCheck=false,
>   locCache=false, keepBinary=false, ackBuf=null, cacheId=-2100569601,
>   initTopVer=null, nodeLeft=false, ignoreClsNotFound=false,
>   asyncCb=false, nodeId=null, routineId=null], bufSize=1, interval=0,
>   autoUnsubscribe=true]}}] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,084 [DEBUG] [23]
>   GridContinuousProcessor - after onDisconnected [rmtInfos={},
>   locInfos={773f91e4-46ee-4066-8271-3db15a8a823d=LocalRoutineInfo
>   [prjPred=null, hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandler
>   [cacheName=ignite-sys-cache, rmtFilter=null, rmtFilterDep=null,
>   internal=true, notifyExisting=false, oldValRequired=true, sync=false,
>   ignoreExpired=true, taskHash=0, skipPrimaryCheck=false,
>   locCache=false, keepBinary=false, ackBuf=null, cacheId=-2100569601,
>   initTopVer=null, nodeLeft=false, ignoreClsNotFound=false,
>   asyncCb=false, nodeId=null, routineId=null], bufSize=1, interval=0,
>   autoUnsubscribe=true]}, clientInfos={}] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,086
>   [DEBUG] [23] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Cancelling grid
>   runnable: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger,
>   igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=26154633,
>   interrupted=false, runner=exchange-worker-#29%null%] 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,087 [DEBUG] [23] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Before
>   joining on exchange worker: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger,
>   igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=26154633,
>   interrupted=true, runner=exchange-worker-#29%null%] 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,087 [DEBUG] [26] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Caught
>   interrupted exception: java.lang.InterruptedException 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,087 [DEBUG] [23] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Joining
>   grid runnable: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger,
>   igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=26154633,
>   interrupted=false, runner=exchange-worker-#29%null%] 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,087 [DEBUG] [26] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Grid
>   runnable finished due to cancellation: partition-exchanger 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,087 [DEBUG] [23] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Cache
>   manager received onKernalStop() callback. 2017-09-04 17:14:11,087
>   [DEBUG] [23] GridCacheDeploymentManager - Cache manager received
>   onKernalStop() callback. 2017-09-04 17:14:11,092 [DEBUG] [23]
>   GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Cache manager stopped. 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,092 [DEBUG] [23] GridCacheDeploymentManager - Cache manager
>   stopped. 2017-09-04 17:14:11,095 [DEBUG] [23]
>   GridDeploymentPerVersionStore - Unregistered deployment discovery
>   listener:
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentPerVersionStore$1@107a0d6
>   2017-09-04 17:14:11,095 [DEBUG] [23] GridDeploymentPerLoaderStore -
>   Unregistered deployment discovery listener:
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentPerLoaderStore$1@2114ba
>   2017-09-04 17:14:11,096 [DEBUG] [23] GridDeploymentPerVersionStore -
>   Deployment store stopped: GridDeploymentPerVersionStore
>   [missedRsrcCacheSize=100, loadRmtLock=GridStripedLock
>   [concurrency=16]] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,096 [DEBUG] [23]
>   GridDeploymentPerLoaderStore - Deployment store stopped:
>   GridDeploymentPerLoaderStore
>   [ctxLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@387f44] 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,096 [DEBUG] [23] GridDeploymentLocalStore - Deployment store
>   stopped: GridDeploymentLocalStore [] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,096 [DEBUG]
>   [23] GridDeploymentLocalStore - Deployment store started:
>   GridDeploymentLocalStore [] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,096 [DEBUG] [23]
>   GridDeploymentPerLoaderStore - Deployment store started:
>   GridDeploymentPerLoaderStore
>   [ctxLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@387f44] 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,096 [DEBUG] [23] GridDeploymentPerVersionStore - Deployment
>   store started: GridDeploymentPerVersionStore [missedRsrcCacheSize=100,
>   loadRmtLock=GridStripedLock [concurrency=16]] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,097
>   [INFO ] [23] TcpDiscoverySpi - Client node disconnected from cluster,
>   will try to reconnect with new id
>   [newId=5c0e3431-da78-4fe3-9638-8d587763fd3a,
>   prevId=341136db-9447-4abe-ad06-c10915c3e671, locNode=TcpDiscoveryNode
>   [id=341136db-9447-4abe-ad06-c10915c3e671, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
>   127.0.0.1, 161.27.44.226], sockAddrs=[/161.27.44.226:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=0,
>   lastExchangeTime=1504537928695, loc=true,
>   ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:a6ca5c8a, isClient=true]] 2017-09-04
>   17:14:11,098 [DEBUG] [23] TcpDiscoverySpi - Resolved addresses from IP
>   finder: [/161.27.45.134:47501, /161.27.45.134:47503,
>   /161.27.45.134:47500, /161.27.45.134:47509, /161.27.45.134:47507,
>   /161.27.45.134:47504, /161.27.45.134:47502, /161.27.45.134:47505,
>   /161.27.45.134:47506, /161.27.45.134:47508] 2017-09-04 17:14:11,098
>   [DEBUG] [23] TcpDiscoverySpi - Send join
>   request[addr=/161.27.45.134:47501, reconnect=false,
>   locNodeId=5c0e3431-da78-4fe3-9638-8d587763fd3a]

Thank you in advance.

-------------EDIT---------------

This is the log before IgniteClientDisconnectedException:

> 2017-09-05 17:00:43,366 [DEBUG] [17] SqlListenerProcessor - Balancing
>   data [min0=0, minIdx=0, max0=-1, maxIdx=-1] 2017-09-05 17:00:43,399
>   [DEBUG] [46] GridCacheIoManager - Sending cache message
>   [msg=GridNearSingleGetRequest [futId=1504623622044,
>   key=UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=132,
>   val=/Mirafiori/A141/PLX/ST010/010T03BM02/VARIABILEPROVA,
>   hasValBytes=true], flags=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6,
>   minorTopVer=0], subjId=9ecdc65d-d267-4d65-aa20-30657a2cff37,
>   taskNameHash=0, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1], node=ClusterNode
>   [id=eb1c1822-ef9b-4f75-b26f-0fcb98dd72b9, order=1,
>   addr=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 161.27.45.134, 192.168.153.1,
>   192.168.235.1, 2002:a11b:2d86:0:0:0:a11b:2d86], daemon=false]] 2017-09-05 17:00:44,349 [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout
>   has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=2277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623644345, period=3000, cancel=false,
>   task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2@139f51f]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:44,823 [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout
>   has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=3277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623644815, period=3000, cancel=false, task=MetricsUpdater
>   [prevGcTime=38, prevCpuTime=1339,
>   super=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$MetricsUpdater@1b793b4]]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:47,353 [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout
>   has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=2277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623647346, period=3000, cancel=false,
>   task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2@139f51f]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:47,833 [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout
>   has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=3277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623647823, period=3000, cancel=false, task=MetricsUpdater
>   [prevGcTime=38, prevCpuTime=1421,
>   super=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$MetricsUpdater@1b793b4]]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:48,163 [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout
>   has occurred:
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ClientCacheUpdateTimeout@12631ca
>   2017-09-05 17:00:48,165 [DEBUG] [26] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager
>   - Before waiting for exchange futures [futs[], worker=GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false,
>   hashCode=17541516, interrupted=false,
>   runner=exchange-worker-#29%null%]] 2017-09-05 17:00:49,062 [DEBUG]
>   [11] TcpCommunicationSpi - Balancing data [min0=0, minIdx=1, max0=-1,
>   maxIdx=-1] 2017-09-05 17:00:49,367 [DEBUG] [17] SqlListenerProcessor -
>   Balancing data [min0=0, minIdx=0, max0=-1, maxIdx=-1] 2017-09-05
>   17:00:50,115 [DEBUG] [60] TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to get acknowledge
>   for message, will try to reconnect
>   [msg=TcpDiscoveryClientMetricsUpdateMessage
>   [super=TcpDiscoveryAbstractMessage [sndNodeId=null,
>   id=c977e825e51-9ecdc65d-d267-4d65-aa20-30657a2cff37,
>   verifierNodeId=null, topVer=0, pendingIdx=0, failedNodes=null,
>   isClient=true]], timeout=5000] 2017-09-05 17:00:50,115 [ERROR] [60]
>   TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to send message: null 2017-09-05 17:00:50,116
>   [ERROR] [24] TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to read message
>   [sock=Socket[addr=/161.27.45.134,port=47500,localport=56216],
>   locNodeId=9ecdc65d-d267-4d65-aa20-30657a2cff37,
>   rmtNodeId=eb1c1822-ef9b-4f75-b26f-0fcb98dd72b9] 2017-09-05
>   17:00:50,116 [DEBUG] [23] TcpDiscoverySpi - Connection closed, will
>   try to restore connection. 2017-09-05 17:00:50,117 [ERROR] [24]
>   TcpDiscoverySpi - Connection failed
>   [sock=Socket[addr=/161.27.45.134,port=47500,localport=56216],
>   locNodeId=9ecdc65d-d267-4d65-aa20-30657a2cff37] 2017-09-05
>   17:00:50,121 [DEBUG] [61] TcpDiscoverySpi - Started reconnect process
>   [join=false, timeout=5000] 2017-09-05 17:00:50,122 [DEBUG] [61]
>   TcpDiscoverySpi - Resolved addresses from IP finder:
>   [/161.27.45.134:47508, /161.27.45.134:47501, /161.27.45.134:47500,
>   /161.27.45.134:47509, /161.27.45.134:47503, /161.27.45.134:47506,
>   /161.27.45.134:47504, /161.27.45.134:47505, /161.27.45.134:47502,
>   /161.27.45.134:47507] 2017-09-05 17:00:50,122 [DEBUG] [61]
>   TcpDiscoverySpi - Send join request [addr=/161.27.45.134:47508,
>   reconnect=true, locNodeId=9ecdc65d-d267-4d65-aa20-30657a2cff37]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:53,166 [DEBUG] [26] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager
>   - Before waiting for exchange futures [futs[], worker=GridWorker 
>   [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false,
>   hashCode=17541516, interrupted=false,
>   runner=exchange-worker-#29%null%]] 2017-09-05 17:00:53,364 [DEBUG]
>   [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=2277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623653355, period=3000, cancel=false,
>   task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2@139f51f]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:53,841 [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout
>   has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=3277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623653832, period=3000, cancel=false, task=MetricsUpdater
>   [prevGcTime=38, prevCpuTime=1445,
>   super=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$MetricsUpdater@1b793b4]]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:55,063 [DEBUG] [11] TcpCommunicationSpi - Balancing
>   data [min0=0, minIdx=0, max0=-1, maxIdx=-1] 2017-09-05 17:00:55,123
>   [ERROR] [61] TcpDiscoverySpi - Exception on joining: connect timed out
>   2017-09-05 17:00:55,368 [DEBUG] [17] SqlListenerProcessor - Balancing
>   data [min0=0, minIdx=0, max0=-1, maxIdx=-1] 2017-09-05 17:00:56,368
>   [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout has occurred:
>   CancelableTask [id=2277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623656362, period=3000, cancel=false,
>   task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2@139f51f]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:56,842 [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout
>   has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=3277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623656835, period=3000, cancel=false, task=MetricsUpdater
>   [prevGcTime=38, prevCpuTime=1460,
>   super=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$MetricsUpdater@1b793b4]]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:58,167 [DEBUG] [26] GridCachePartitionExchangeManager
>   - Before waiting for exchange futures [futs[], worker=GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false,
>   hashCode=17541516, interrupted=false,
>   runner=exchange-worker-#29%null%]] 2017-09-05 17:00:59,369 [DEBUG]
>   [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=2277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623659362, period=3000, cancel=false,
>   task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2@139f51f]
>   2017-09-05 17:00:59,837 [DEBUG] [10] GridTimeoutProcessor - Timeout
>   has occurred: CancelableTask
>   [id=3277e825e51-7ede3b3f-c331-45d1-864b-a8c1c9f4fbb2,
>   endTime=1504623659836, period=3000, cancel=false, task=MetricsUpdater
>   [prevGcTime=38, prevCpuTime=1476,
>   super=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$MetricsUpdater@1b793b4]]
>   2017-09-05 17:01:00,125 [ERROR] [61] TcpDiscoverySpi - Exception on
>   joining: connect timed out 2017-09-05 17:01:00,125 [DEBUG] [61]
>   TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to join to address
>   [addr=/161.27.45.134:47508, recon=true,
>   errs=[java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out,
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]] 2017-09-05
>   17:01:00,125 [DEBUG] [61] TcpDiscoverySpi - Send join request
>   [addr=/161.27.45.134:47501, reconnect=true,
>   locNodeId=9ecdc65d-d267-4d65-aa20-30657a2cff37]

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share logs before IgniteClientDisconnectedException for a more than 60s? Logs started when you simulate that the ethernet cable is disconnected should help

Comment: I did. Thank you for your cooperation

Comment: Are you sure that this is full log? I see that it's cover only 2 seconds

Comment: How do you simulate a network failure?

Comment: Evgenii: I reedit taking more seconds.

Comment: Denis: I simulated by removing the ethernet cable from my pc leaving the Ignite client and server active. The Ignite server is in another PC.

Comment: Did you try to remove all manually set timeouts except for failureDetectionTimeout. Documentation says that it controls failure timeout and it is ignored if other timeouts are explicitly set.

Comment: yes, i already try that but nothing...